# Databricks SQL Update table based on Pandas DF

Tags: pandas, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a Databricks SQL table as follows

| personId | date_start |
| --- | --- |
| ab3c2n | 2/4/22 |
| ajf2o0 | Null |
| 0j20jj | Null |
| 20fj00 | Null |

In reality there are 50+ columns and hundreds of entries in the table.
I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks as follows. It has only these two columns

| personId | date_start |
| --- | --- |
| ajf2o0 | 12/10/22 |
| 0j20jj | 12/11/22 |

It will only have entries for a subset of the folks with Null date_start values in the SQL table.

I want to update the SQL table with the correct date_start values per person.

I can do this by iterating row by row and executing a query for each person but this seems horribly inefficient. Is there a way to tell Databricks to match on the personId and update the date_start value?

Thanks in advance!

For now I'm giving everyone the same start date in the SQL table if their Id is in the dataframe. start_today_personId is a Pandas series with just the personId values from the pandas dataframe.

```
sql_query = f"""UPDATE db.person SET date_start = current_date() WHERE personId in ( {','.join(map(str, start_today_personId.tolist()))} ) """
            
spark.sql(sql_query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can convert the Pandas dataframe to Pyspark dataframe and then create a view for that**. By using this view, you can update your Databricks SQL table.

**This is my sample Databricks SQL table:**

[image]

Create a temporary view from pyspark dataframe.

```
sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(pandas_dataframe) 
sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView('sample1')
```

[image]

Now you can use this view to update your table as per your requirement. For sample I have used merge.

```
%sql
MERGE INTO person
USING sample1
ON person.persond = sample1.persond
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET date_start = sample1.date_start
```

[image]

**Databricks SQL table after updating:**

[image]

Comment: At first this didn't work (no error message, just no writing) because the date field in the data frame was not formatted as DateTime. After converting it in Pandas it worked!